# How to stop service when application crash

Tags: android, service, notifications

I am making one application,which download set of files.so i started one service which download files continuously so that notification is also there it represents current download status,my problem is when application got crash.Notification is not dismissed,and service still running in the background.I tried to stop service in ondestroy of service but it didn't work for me,please help me

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Stopping

> A started service must manage its own lifecycle. That is, the system
>   does not stop or destroy the service unless it must recover system
>   memory and the service continues to run after onStartCommand()
>   returns. So, the service must stop itself by calling stopSelf() or
>   another component can stop it by calling stopService().

Examples:

1- calling `stopSelf()` after work is done.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Use a Thread to not block your UI when doing operations over the network.
        // See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html for more information.
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                downloadSetOfFiles();
                stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

2- manually calling `stopService()`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class));
                // Note: If clients are bound to the service, 
                // then the service will only stop after all clients are unbound.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you can't manually stop your service because your app crashed, then the service needs to stop itself when the operation of downloading files is over by calling `stopSelf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve this by destroying it on the MainActivity onDestroy method? so, when your app crash it will be stop the service.

Comment: i am downloading files in background so whenever i press back button it destroy application so my download stops,what i need whenever application got crash that time only stop the service